# Running an Income Statement report from QBO using IPP

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I use the QBSDK AppendGeneralSummaryReportQueryRq object to do this for the desktop version. Is running reports supported in the IPP for QBOnline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of the QuickBooks Online APIs supports any reporting right now.